# Masking a 2D numpy array by comparing elements to a 1D list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I'm given a 2D numpy array and a list of numbers that look like this:

```
[1 2 3 1]
[2 3 1 2]
[3 1 2 3]
[1 2 3 1]

[1, 3]
```

I need to find some way to generate a boolean array where every element that's in the list results in a True in a 2D array

```
[True False True True]
[False True True False]
[True True False True]
[True False True True]
```

I've tried looping through the list and using logical_or to combine the boolean masks that it creates, but the 2D array is a large image and the list can be upwards of 300 elements long, which becomes very slow very quickly.

If there's some operation in numpy that looks like `array in list` similar to `array == list[0]`, I can't find it but it would be very helpful.

My code currently looks like

```
boolean_array = array == mask_list[0]
for list_element in mask_list[0:]:
    boolean_array = np.logical_or(blank_boolean, array == list_element)

return boolean_array
```

(np.where, np.any, np.all have also been tried but i cant wrap my head around how to do it)

(also both sets are always integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.isin`

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 1, 2],
    [3, 1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 1]
])

valid = np.array([1, 3])

print(np.isin(arr, valid))

[[ True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it was that easy lol

Comment: @GooseChair The boffins who code numpy really have thought of everything